# Is Android Studio blocking my web scraper from connecting to the internet?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I have created a web scraper for my android application. I have finished and tested it external to the app and Android Studio, and it works perfectly. Unfortunately, when I migrated it into my app and android studio I wasn't able to connect to the websites anymore. I was still able to run the code externally and the websites were up and running but when the code was in android studio it doesn't seem to work.

This is very weird as I have managed to run a web scraper in the app before and the only relevant thing that I can think of that I have change which might affect it was creating a web view in another activity. This meant I had to edit the manifest to allow the app to use the Internet. But why would this stop the web scraper from being able to connect?

I will be uploading my project to GitHub soon if it would help to give a link to the code.

Comment: Android Studio is a development environment. It does not run your application code, it simply compiles it. So the direct answer to your question is "no." There is a different underlying issue unrelated to Android Studio.

Comment: Did you solve this?  Is your code on GitHub? I'm unclear about your question. Do you mean that the web scraper works on the physical android hardware, but does not work in the emulated hardware that is launched from Android Studio?